# SQLite source code parse.y - nm

Tags: sqlite, compiler-construction, grammar, bison, bnf

I am reading the [grammar](https://github.com/mackyle/sqlite/blob/master/src/parse.y#L247) of SQLite and having a few questions about the following paragraph.

```
// The name of a column or table can be any of the following:
//
%type nm {Token}
nm(A) ::= id(A). 
nm(A) ::= STRING(A). 
nm(A) ::= JOIN_KW(A).
```

The `nm` has been used quite widely in the program. The [lemon parser](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/doc/lemon.html#ptype) documentation said

> Typically the data type of a non-terminal is a pointer to the root of
>   a parse-tree structure that contains all information about that
>   non-terminal

```
%type   expr  {Expr*}
```

1. Should I understand `{Token}` actually stands for a syntactic grouping which is a non-terminal token that "is a parse-tree structure that contains all.."?
2. What is nm short for in this same, is it simply "name"?
3. What is the period sign (dot `.`) that each nm(A) declaration ends up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you should understand that `Token` is a C object type used for the semantic value of `nm`s.
   (It is defined in `sqliteInt.h` and consists of a pointer to a non-null terminated character array and the length of that array.)
2. The comment immediately above the definition of `nm` starts with the words "the name", which definitely suggests to me that `nm` is an abbreviation for "name", yes. That is also consistent with its semantic type, as above, which is basically a name (or at least a string of characters).
3. All lemon productions end with a dot. It tells lemon where the end of the production is, like semicolons​ indicate to a C compiler where the end of a statement is. This makes it easier to parse  consecutive productions, since otherwise the parser would have to look several symbols ahead to see the `::=`